# Python - different CRC results from special characters

Tags: python, string, unicode, crc32

I'm learning Python 3 and I couldn't find any explanation for the following problem.
I'm using this code to calculate JAMCRC from a byte-string:

```
import zlib

x = b'a'
result = int('0b'+'1'*32,2) - zlib.crc32(x)
print(result)
```

For 'a' it prints `390611388`.
I'm comparing the JAMCRC results calculated by the above script with the third party program (Windows .exe, probably written in .NET or C#).
For the standard ASCII characters and strings, results from both programs (above script and third-party program) are equal.
The problem is that when I try to calculate JAMCRC from a Polish letter, the results from these programs are different. For example, when I set `x` to 'ó' my script prints `211389371`, but that other program for 'ó' prints `155825108`. I'd like to make my script print the same results for Polish letters as they are in the other program. Do you know how to do it and what is causing the difference with Polish characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python defaults to using Unicode](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), specifically UTF-8. [Windows, however, apparently defaults to ISO 8859 encoding](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html). Using this encoding scheme results in the same CRC:

```
In [1]: x = 'ó'.encode('utf8')

In [2]: print(int('0b'+'1'*32,2) - zlib.crc32(x))
211389371

In [3]: x = 'ó'.encode('8859')

In [4]: print(int('0b'+'1'*32,2) - zlib.crc32(x))
155825108
```

EDIT: The above worked for me in Python 3.7. See @daxim's comment below for a link to the list of all available encodings. **This code won't work as-is in Python 2** because Python 2 strings are encoded in ASCII/latin-1, whereas Python 3 strings are encoded in Unicode. You'll need to look up specifically how to handle unicode strings in Python 2 if that's what you need. *I'll caveat that by saying that* Python 2 is end-of-life beginning in 2020; it's been on the way out for years, and if you're writing new code, it really ought to be in Python 3 (the example code above being a good motivation).

Comment: It works for 'ó' but for 'ł' and other letters I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256). How can I fix this?

Comment: `8859` is not a valid encoding name ([full list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets)). One cannot just use some common occuring substring and then expect a programming language to pick one from the candidates, computers cannot read minds yet. –– `U+0142 ‹ł› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE}` is encoded in [cp852](http://enwp.org/cp852).

Comment: Thank you, but I still get different CRC results from both programs. Is it possible to calculate JAMCRC without converting the string to bytes?

Comment: CRC always works on bytes, by definition. You have an encoding problem. Make the encodings the same and you will have the same bytes, and hence, the same CRC.

Comment: @daxim I've tried all available encodings from both lists provided by you and @scnerd and for the letter 'ł' CRC results are never equal to that other Windows program :-( When I set encoding to `cp852` the results for 'ó' are equal, but for 'ł' are different. How is this possible?

Comment: @daxim I know the machine can't read my mind, but the example code shown above is actual output from my IPython session (3.7). It worked there by coincidence, and I didn't see the need to dig deeper.

Comment: @Marek As daxim says, the results of the CRC function are deterministic on the input *bytes*, but of course encodings can be a huge pain to figure out. You might try pasting the character into notepad, saving the file, then checking what the file's bytes are. Try the Python CRC function on those bytes and see if the results are the same. You may be able to hunt around to figure out which encoding Windows is using based on the pairing of those bytes to that character.